# Automatically upload local changes into windows azure / amazon s3 cloud server

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, amazon-s3, azure-storage, continuous-deployment

I have to create a Visual Studio project with the following functionality,

1. Once the project is created, the **service** should automatically upload the project files in to cloud storage (using windows azure or amazon s3 server).
2. If any changes in the project files, instead of uploading the whole project, only the modified files has to be uploaded. ( like SVN commit).

Could anyone please let me know if you have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is more-or-less what "git deployment" is about - deploying changes to a web site or application by pushing the changes from a local git repository to a remote one. The deployment triggers a service or script on the remote repository that updates your site.

Azure supports this for Azure Web Sites. See for example [Continuous deployment using GIT in Azure App Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/) for a step-by-step guid on how to create a new site, deploy and update it using Git.

The engine that automates git deployments in Azure is available as an open source project, [Project Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) which can be hosted outside Azure, eg on your own web server.

Amazon doesn't offer *all* of this out of the box. Its Elastic Beanstalk offering allows you to publish an ASP.NET MVC project to a specific configuration (VMs, settings etc) right from Visual Studio but it's a manual process and doesn't deploy only changes. Check [How to Deploy an Application Using Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitVS/latest/UserGuide/deploy-the-web-application-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk.html) for a step-by-step guide.

You can use Project Kudu on an Amazon VM to use git deployment. This won't set up the VMs as Beanstalk does, but it will deploy only the changes to your site.